# iOS receive payment from Apple Pay as merchant

Tags: ios, applepay

How do I view all transactions maid in the iOS app with Apple Pay? I am a merchant/receiver of Apple Pay. When I test (as client) I see the money is leaving my account but where do I see what is the receiving account?

After googling for a while I see there are Stripe and other payment processing applications. Is there a way to see it just from developer account or app store connect (I don't see any transactions but money left my account)?

P.S. I'm not a person who set up Apple Payment, but have access now.

Comment: Payments made through ApplePay are captured by your payment processor (e.g. Stripe).  You will see details of payments in whatever system the payment processor makes available.  You don't see any details in App Store Connect since the payment is not processed by Apple or the App Store

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. So is it possible that iOS app doesn't use any payment processor integration but the app users are charged? Will I be able to see previous payments (before integrating) once I start using some payment processor? Please put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Are you using in-app purchase or Apple Pay?  If the app uses in-app purchase, then then purchase is processed by Apple and you can see those details in AppStore Connect. No payment processor is required. For Apple Pay, a payment processor is always used.

Comment: Apple Pay. Is it possible to be charged without payment processor or does it mean processor is used if money leaves the account. Put your comment as answer. I will accept it. It was confusing that Apple Pay payments require some processor as well. I assumed it  will be like with PayPal.

Comment: In the case of PayPal, they take care of the credit card transaction; you then need to transfer the funds from your PayPal balance to your bank account.  ApplePay is the same as accepting credit cards directly; you need to have a relationship with a processor to handle the transaction and the money is typically delivered directly to your bank account after the transaction settles (typically a few days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ApplePay you must have a merchant agreement in place with an ApplePay transaction processor.  Stripe is one, but there are others.

This agreement is independent of the developer agreement you have with Apple.

The details of your ApplePay receipts are available from your transaction processor, not Apple.

In the case of PayPal, they take care of the credit card transaction; you then need to transfer the funds from your PayPal balance to your bank account.

With ApplePay you need to have a relationship with a processor to handle the transaction and the money is typically delivered directly to your bank account after the transaction settles (typically a few days)